# CakePHP: syntax error, unexpected T_LIST, expecting T_STRING

Tags: cakephp, syntax-error

my cakephp app throws me that error,on that line:

```
class List extends AppModel {
```

and i cannot understand why.

the whole List.php model file is:

```
<?php

App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class List extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }
    return true;
}
?>
```

Does anybody has an idea why this is happening?

thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### List is a reserved keyword in PHP

You're getting this error, because `list` is a reserved keyword in PHP and therefore cannot be used as the name of your class;

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Rename your model to something else and you should be fine. To still use the same database-table, manually specify the database-table that the model uses via the `useTable` property;

```
class MyList extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'lists';
}
```

Comment: It's easily overlooked :) Glad I could help